# How to check for an undef value in a Matrix (in Julia) and assign a new value?

Tags: matrix, tuples, julia, undef

I want to create a matrix A of undefined values and have the following code that works just fine.

```
A = Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Array{Int64, 1}}}(undef, 100, 100)
```

Later, I want to check if a particular cell is undefined and if so, assign a value after computing it. I tried `isdefined(A, i, j)` but that gave an error for too many arguments. How can I check for `#undef` and assign only if it is undefined?

The documentation on `isdefined` provides a method only for a single dimensional array, how do I achieve the same on a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isassigned`:

```
julia> A[2,3]=(3.0, [])
(3.0, Any[])

julia> isassigned(A,2,3)
true

julia> isassigned(A,3,3)
false
```

Comment: Strange. The documentation of `isassigned` indicates that only linear indices can be used, but your example works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isassigned` function (which is mentioned in the help string of `isdefined`, btw). Like `isdefined` it appears to only accept linear indices, but you can get those from `LinearIndices`.

```
julia> A = Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Array{Int64, 1}}}(undef, 100, 100);

julia> A[5, 4] = (2.1, [5])
(2.1, [5])

julia> isassigned(A, LinearIndices(A)[1, 1])
false

julia> isassigned(A, LinearIndices(A)[5, 4])
true
```

Edit: As demonstrated in the answer from @PrzemyslawSzufel, you don't need linear indices. Seems to be be undocumented, though, up to and including v1.5.1

Comment: <strike>The linear restriction is somewhat weird, though.</strike> Ha, it's just missing from the docs, at least in 1.3.